# enum rawValue constructor ignoring case

Tags: swift2

```
enum DocumentType : String
{
    case
    Any = "Any",
    DL = "DL",
    Passport = "Passport",
    Invalid
}
```

I'm using rawValue constructor like so

```
if let d = DocumentType(rawValue: type) {
```

to parse whatever comes from the server.

Now, suppose a serverside dim bulb changed DL to Dl server side ->
parser breaks defaulting to Invalid.

Are there provisions for windows-developer proofing the parser
short of writing manually a long if else daisy?
same issue with the morons changing the case of keys in json.
need some way to read out of json in a not-so-good-developer-resistant way.
Thanks.

Comment: In future, stick to our [behavior policies](https://stackoverflow.com/help/behavior) please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you can ignore case but you could create an initialiser to prevent your particular issue without a chain of if/else statements:

```
enum DocumentType : String
{
    case
    Any = "Any",
    DL = "DL",
    Passport = "Passport",
    Invalid
    init?(raw:String) {
        let str = raw.characters.count > 2 ?  raw.capitalizedString : raw.uppercaseString
        if let d = DocumentType(rawValue: str) {
            self = d
        }
        else {
            return nil
        }
    }

}

if let d = DocumentType(raw: "ANY") {
    print("success!")
}
```

Answer (score 3):

A generic extension to work for all *relevant* enums. Enum must adhere to `String` and `CaseIterable` protocol for this to work.

```
import Foundation
extension CaseIterable where Self:RawRepresentable, RawValue == String  {
    init?(rawValueIgnoreCase: RawValue) {
        if let caseFound = Self.allCases.first(where: { $0.rawValue.caseInsensitiveCompare(rawValueIgnoreCase) == .orderedSame }) {
            self = caseFound
        } else {
            self.init(rawValue: rawValueIgnoreCase)
        }
    }
}

enum FooBar: String, CaseIterable {
    case foo
    case bar = "BAR"
}

let foo = FooBar(rawValueIgnoreCase: "foo")
let FOO = FooBar(rawValueIgnoreCase: "FOO")
let FoO = FooBar(rawValueIgnoreCase: "FoO")
let bar = FooBar(rawValueIgnoreCase: "bar")
let Bar = FooBar(rawValueIgnoreCase: "Bar")
let BAR = FooBar(rawValueIgnoreCase: "BAR")
let oops = FooBar(rawValueIgnoreCase: "oops") // nil
```

Answer (score 0):

We can do this by using changing the cases while initialising the enum.

```
 enum DocumentType : String {
    case any = "ANY"
    case dl = "DL"
    case passport = "PASSPORT"
    case invalid = "INVALID"

    //If you want to display status in UI define your display name
    var documentDisplayType: String {
     switch self  {
       case .any:
            return "Any"
       case .dl:
            return "Driving License"
       case .passport:
            return "Passport"
       case invalid:
            return "Not proper document"
    }
}
```

While initaliziing changed the respose document type to upper case using `uppercased()` function.

```
 let type = "Dl"
 let docType = DocumentType(rawValue: type.uppercased())
 print(docType.documentDisplayType) // Prints DL
```